# React Native "No bundle URL present" Release Mode Only

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm getting "No bundle url present." only when trying to run in release mode in xcode. I can run the app fine in debug mode.

I ran `react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle` and it gives me the following error:

```
Unexpected token: keyword (default)
```

It doesn't show any line numbers or files that the error might be from. Is there a better way to get more context around this error?

I also tried removing build folder, npm run clean, remove node_modules folder, yarn install with no luck.

This same exact build was working for me a few days ago, so not sure what changed. I'm still on the same version of MacOS, xcode, and react native.

```
RN = 0.43.3
Xcode = 8.3.2
MacOS = Sierra 10.12.5
```

Comment: Did u manage to fix this? I have the same problem now

Comment: I am also having this error. It started showing up in my CI yesterday, and messed with both my Android and iOS builds. 
On iOS it doesn't even "fail" the build, it silently finishes the build and makes the app crash on launch (throwing the error you have experienced)
On Android it fails during the `:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets` phase.
I am having a hard time reproducing this locally, though. Have you found any clues on what's causing this?

Comment: The issue solved itself for me after a while (appr. 1 day).
I assume it was related to a dependency or my building environment (remote CI).

Comment: Still haven't managed to fix this issue, it's driving me insane! It started yesterday and still doesn't work. There is an issue on GitHub, but all the advice in that thread hasn't worked for me: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12754. Please let me know if you guys manage to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by upgrading watchman. Here are the steps I took:

- `brew update`
- `brew unlink watchman`
- `brew install watchman`
- I ran `npm run clean` which I have set to do this:

  ```
  rm -rf ios/build; rm -rf ios/build; rm -rf android/build; rm -rf android/app/build; rm -rf $TMPDIR/react* ; rm -f ios/main.jsbundle; rm -rf node_modules; rm yarn.lock || true; npm cache clean; yarn cache clean
  ```
- `yarn install` or `npm install`, if you aren't using yarn

Hopefully this helps others having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved by running the following command in the root directory of the project:

```
rm -rf ios/build/; kill $(lsof -t -i:8081); react-native run-ios
```

This command will remove the build folder from the iOS project, kill any other process running on port 8081, and re-run.

Answer (score 0):

Removed `node_modules` and did `npm install` again and the error went away. Seems like someone had a typo...

Comment: I've tried this multiple times and I still have the same issue. Xcode builds with no errors, but on launch of the app it crashes with the error I listed above. I think it has to do with some node module or dependency somewhere, but not sure.